# How to debug on GNOME Shell 3.6, 3.8 or newer

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I developed my own gnome-shell extension that worked on GNOME Shell 3.4 and GNOME Shell 3.6. It's not working on GNOME Shell 3.8 and I can't find out why because I don't know where to access to any logs.

On GNOME Shell 3.4, using Looking Glass, there was a 'Error' tab that was removed on the 3.6 and 3.8 version, and I can't see any errors. On the extensions tab, clicking on 'show the errors' says 'no errors'.

Launching the gnome-shell --replace for terminal doesn't show any errors either. But my extension is not displayed (the code is the same and works on GNOME 3.4 and 3.6).

How can I debug this in order to find what's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

The extension: https://github.com/Softcatala/TraductorGnomeShell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All output is redirected to stout/stderr this is captured in

.cache/gdm/session.log or .xsession-errors

Comment: Thanks Guido. May I ask something else: how do I add my own logs to this file from my code? (something like global.log(xx)?, but this doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 2):

Since Gnome 3.6+ the error message tab was removed from Looking Glass.
On a Gnome 3.6+ system open a console and issue the command:

```
tail -f .xsession-errors
```

In your extension use the new logging syntax:

```
log('my message');
```

In your console you will then see:

```
JS LOG: my message
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fedora 19 log function mentioned in @mbokil answer writes to `/var/log/messages`

```
tail -f messages | grep 'localhost gnome-session'
```

will be your friend.